# JPEG to TIFF using minimagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, minimagick

I wanted to convert my jpeg image to a tiff image with some criteria, all the factor is met but I am not able to figure out how to decrease the size, currently, the image is becoming 1.2MB after conversion, I want to decrease it to less than or equal 100kb with resolution of 200 dpi.
The original jpeg image is 250kb with 456 X 679.

How to do it?

```
require 'mini_magick'

class FileConversionService

  def self.to_tiff
    input_path = "/images/1.jpg"
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(input_path)
    k = image.format("tiff")
    k.write("/images/1_tiff")
    tiff_path = "/images/1_tiff"
    image_data = MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |img|
        img << tiff_path
      img << '-resize' << "1600x734"
      img << '-colorspace' << "scRGB"
      img << '-density' << "700"
      img << '-background' << "white"
      img << '-verbose'
      img << tiff_path
    end
  end

end

FileConversionService.to_tiff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `-compress` option with `ZIP` or `LZW` option to enable compression for  the TIFF. But for most images TIFF will be bigger than JPEG. An in addition you specified the `resize` option, which upscales your image to 979x734, making it a bigger image.

As additional comment, your current code converts twice, one time via

```
input_path = "/images/1.jpg"
image = MiniMagick::Image.open(input_path)
k = image.format("tiff")
k.write("/images/1_tiff")
tiff_path = "/images/1_tiff"
```

which opens the jpg and writes the tiff and the second time doing

```
image_data = MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |img|
    img << tiff_path
  img << '-resize' << "1600x734"
  img << '-colorspace' << "scRGB"
  img << '-density' << "700"
  img << '-background' << "white"
  img << '-verbose'
  img << tiff_path
end
```

which reopens the tiff file, adjusts it to the defined parameters and then outputs it again to `tiff_path`. This can be done in one go using only convert:

```
input_path = "/images/1.jpg"
tiff_path = "/images/1.tiff"
MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |img|
  img << input_path
  img << '-compress' << 'ZIP'      
  img << '-resize' << "1600x734"
  img << '-colorspace' << "scRGB"
  img << '-density' << "700"
  img << '-background' << "white"
  img << tiff_path
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Bruno but compress is not fulfilling the factor of keeping file size less than or equal to 100kb. What shall I do to keep it <= 100kb for all the images.

Comment: I don't know, if imagemagick supports something like this. You could ask in their discussion section on github https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/discussions, maybe someone there has an idea.